# convert a list containing objects, to a list containing a specific function or properties of those objects

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

given that:

```
obj_list = [obj0, obj1, obj2, obj3...]
```

I'd like:

```
names_list = [obj0.name(), obj1.name(), obj2.name(), obj3.name()...]
paths_list = [obj0.path(), obj1.path(), obj2.path(), obj3.path()...]
```

so for debug purposes I can do:

```
print names_list
```

or

```
if my_path not in paths_list ...
```

of course I could just do

```
name_list =[]
path_list = []
for obj in obj_list:
    name_list.append(obj.name())
    path_list.append(obj.path())
```

But then I might as well write this in C. Surely there's a python way of doing this in one little command, but I couldn't find it.

I'm using python 2.7 by the way

Comment: Honestly the loop is a perfectly fine way of writing this. If you want additional syntatic-sugar then you might want to have a look at list comprehensions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
names_list = [obj.name() for obj in obj_list]
```

Answer (score 4):

The (syntactically) easy way of doing this in Python is with [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)

```
names_list = map(lambda x: x.name(), obj_list)
```

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote so I might improve my answer?

Comment: It's not wrong (the downvote is unwarranted, in my opinion), but list comprehensions are generally preferred to `map`.

Comment: @chepner, fair enough, I can accept that.  Just wanted to make sure I didn't make a silly typo or something

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`operator.methodcaller`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller), like this

```
from operator import methodcaller
get_name, get_path = methodcaller("name"), methodcaller("path")
names, paths = map(get_name, obj_list), map(get_path, obj_list)
```